# Filter out an array of object removing elements with same values

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this one:

```js
const data = [
  { source: "actor0", target: "actor1", value: 2 },
  { source: "actor0", target: "actor2", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor0", target: "actor3", value: 2 },
  { source: "actor0", target: "actor4", value: 3 },
  { source: "actor1", target: "actor0", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor1", target: "actor2", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor1", target: "actor3", value: 3 },
  { source: "actor1", target: "actor4", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor2", target: "actor0", value: 3 },
  { source: "actor2", target: "actor1", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor3", target: "actor0", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor3", target: "actor1", value: 2 },
  { source: "actor3", target: "actor2", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor4", target: "actor0", value: 2 },
  { source: "actor4", target: "actor2", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor4", target: "actor3", value: 2 }
];
```

It represents some links of a network. Since my network is not directional, I'm not interested to links with same source ad target.
I mean, I have `{ source: "actor0", target: "actor1", value: 2 }` so I can remove `{ source: "actor2", target: "actor0", value: 3 }` (`value` is not important).

So the result should be:

```js
const filteredData = [
  { source: "actor0", target: "actor1", value: 2 },
  { source: "actor0", target: "actor2", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor0", target: "actor3", value: 2 },
  { source: "actor0", target: "actor4", value: 3 },
  // { source: "actor1", target: "actor0", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor1", target: "actor2", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor1", target: "actor3", value: 3 },
  { source: "actor1", target: "actor4", value: 1 },
  // { source: "actor2", target: "actor0", value: 3 },
  // { source: "actor2", target: "actor1", value: 1 },
  // { source: "actor3", target: "actor0", value: 1 },
  // { source: "actor3", target: "actor1", value: 2 },
  { source: "actor3", target: "actor2", value: 1 },
  // { source: "actor4", target: "actor0", value: 2 },
  { source: "actor4", target: "actor2", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor4", target: "actor3", value: 2 }
];
```

How can I do that? I know it should be simple but I have no idea how to do that. Maybe using a `Set` but how?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to remove the duplicates in the `data` array.

We'd create a grouping key based on `source` and `target`. We'll sort to ensure that order is not relevant, that is 'actor0-actor1' is the same key as 'actor1-actor0'.

Once we've grouped the items, we'll convert to an array again with `Object.values()`

```js
const data = [ { source: "actor0", target: "actor1", value: 2 }, { source: "actor0", target: "actor2", value: 1 }, { source: "actor0", target: "actor3", value: 2 }, { source: "actor0", target: "actor4", value: 3 }, { source: "actor1", target: "actor0", value: 1 }, { source: "actor1", target: "actor2", value: 1 }, { source: "actor1", target: "actor3", value: 3 }, { source: "actor1", target: "actor4", value: 1 }, { source: "actor2", target: "actor0", value: 3 }, { source: "actor2", target: "actor1", value: 1 }, { source: "actor3", target: "actor0", value: 1 }, { source: "actor3", target: "actor1", value: 2 }, { source: "actor3", target: "actor2", value: 1 }, { source: "actor4", target: "actor0", value: 2 }, { source: "actor4", target: "actor2", value: 1 }, { source: "actor4", target: "actor3", value: 2 } ];

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, { source, target, value }) => { 
    const key = [source, target].sort().join('-'); 
    acc[key] = acc[key] || { source, target, value };
    return acc;
}, {}))

console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to filter out your items, based on a particular `find` condition. The condition being your source and target are matching or not.

Take each individual item from the array and search the array again based on that item. If the indices match, then we have the same item, so you can allow it. But if not, then you can discard the item,

This can be done using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const data = [
  { source: "actor0", target: "actor1", value: 2 },
  { source: "actor0", target: "actor2", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor0", target: "actor3", value: 2 },
  { source: "actor0", target: "actor4", value: 3 },
  { source: "actor1", target: "actor0", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor1", target: "actor2", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor1", target: "actor3", value: 3 },
  { source: "actor1", target: "actor4", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor2", target: "actor0", value: 3 },
  { source: "actor2", target: "actor1", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor3", target: "actor0", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor3", target: "actor1", value: 2 },
  { source: "actor3", target: "actor2", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor4", target: "actor0", value: 2 },
  { source: "actor4", target: "actor2", value: 1 },
  { source: "actor4", target: "actor3", value: 2 }
];

let ans = data.filter((x,ind) => {
const findI = data.findIndex((y) => {
if(y.source === x.source && y.target === x.target) return true;
if(y.target === x.source && y.source === x.target) return true;
else return false;
});
if(findI === ind) return true;
});

console.log(ans);
```